# How do I make Xcode accept paths in #include statements?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, include, objective-c++

In one file in Xcode, I'm writing:

```
#include "mass/gravity_tool.h"
```

And it keeps complaining that the file can't be found. However, if I change it to just:

```
#include "gravity_tool.h"
```

It finds it fine.

The .h file is indeed within a "mass" folder I dragged into Xcode.

I can't just change it to remove the path because this is used throughout dozens of files. Is there a way to get it to accept it as is?

Comment: It's because yours file in same `mass` folder. In files one step over it will be allright.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Can you redrag that dozens of files one folder above or create another mass-folder inside mass?

Comment: You can try removing the files from the project, then add the mass folder location on the project settings.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Apologies if I wasn't clear, but no, I cannot. The whole `mass/*` path is used over 100 times throughout the project, as it's cross-platform as well. Changing the file structure would not help, as the issue is in that the path *needs* to include the `mass/` portion.

Comment: @leparlon Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Thinking again, this probably wont work. But I meant removing the files from the project as usual, then adding a pathing to it on the Header Search Path on the settings. (It may not work, depends on how the code is structured)

Comment: Oversimplifying, I said to remove the files from the project, because when you add files to a project in Xcode, it treats all the files as they were in the same folder. That's why you have to remove the folders from the paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in `Header Search Pathes` parent of mass-folder.